# How to mask aadhaar card number from clicked image in android studio

Tags: android, image, android-studio, masking, aadhaar

I have created a camera using file provider. In which I’m supposed to click aadhaar card image.

The requirement is that we need to mask aadhaar card number in the clicked image.

please help.

Answer (score 1):

It Mask Aadhar Number You Write To API And Call

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).